# Harris Feature Detection is not accurate

Tags: matlab, image-processing, feature-detection

I have implemented Harris feature detection algorithm and the results are not accurate as compared to using the inbuilt function of Matlab: corner(I,'Harris'). Any ideas why so? Or am i missing something in it?

Results of my code:

```
  im=imread('D:\lena_256.pgm');
    im=im2double(im);
   % im = double(im(:,:,1));
    sigma = 2;k = 0.04;

    % derivative masks
    s_D = 0.7*sigma;
    x  = -round(3*s_D):round(3*s_D);
    dx = x .* exp(-x.*x/(2*s_D*s_D)) ./ (s_D*s_D*s_D*sqrt(2*pi));
    dy = dx';

    % image derivatives
    Ix = conv2(im, dx, 'same');
    Iy = conv2(im, dy, 'same');

    % sum of the Auto-correlation matrix
    s_I = sigma;
    g = fspecial('gaussian',max(1,fix(6*s_I+1)), s_I);
    Ix2 = conv2(Ix.^2, g, 'same'); % Smoothed squared image derivatives
    Iy2 = conv2(Iy.^2, g, 'same');
    Ixy = conv2(Ix.*Iy, g, 'same');

    % interest point response
      cim = (Ix2.*Iy2 - Ixy.^2) - k*(Ix2 + Iy2).^2; % Original Harris measure.
    %cim=(Ix2.*Iy2 - Ixy.^2)./(Ix2 + Iy2);  %   harmonic mean
    % find local maxima on 3x3 neighborgood
    [r,c,max_local] = findLocalMaximum(cim,3*s_I);

    % set threshold 1% of the maximum value
    t = 0.005*max(max_local(:));

    % find local maxima greater than threshold
    [r,c] = find(max_local>=t);

    % build interest points
    points = [r,c];

    figure, imshow(im),title('Harris Feature Points');
    hold on
    plot(points(:,1),points(:,2),'r*');


function [row,col,max_local] = findLocalMaximum(val,radius)

    mask = fspecial('disk',radius)>0;
    val2 = imdilate(val,mask);
    index = val==val2;
    [row,col] = find(index==1);
    max_local = zeros(size(val));
    max_local(index) = val(index);

end
```

[image]

Results using inbuilt corner() function:

[image]

Comment: Perhaps the default values of MATLAB's Harris corner detector are different in comparison to the parameters you have chosen.  Are you sure you chose the right parameters between both methods?

Comment: It definitely looks like your implementation is missing something.  Most of those points are nowhere near an edge, let alone a corner.  You should post your code.